# Scrolling Opacity Shift To and From Targeted Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to get an overlay div's opacity to fade to black as you approach a targeted element in the middle of the page, and then fade back to transparent after that element exits the viewport.

(Broken) Example: https://jsfiddle.net/dtcgbxcn/3/

As you approach the 'blue' section, it should get darker. The page should be solid black before the blue section enters the viewport. Then, after the blue section exits the viewport, it begins to gradually fade out the opacity.  By the time you reach the bottom of the page (or another targeted element), the overlay should be fully transparent again.

Note that, due to responsiveness, the height of any of these sections is indeterminate.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var st          = $(this).scrollTop(),
        offset      = $('.blue').offset().top - $('.blue').height(),
        opacity     = st / offset;
        _docHeight  = $('.red').height() + $('.blue').height() + $('.yellow').height();

    $('.overlay').height(_docHeight);

    if (opacity > 2) {
        opacity = 3 - opacity;  
    }

    $('.overlay').css('opacity', opacity);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fiddled around with your example, Hopefully this is what you were looking for as far as functionality. It should be 100 opacity right before the blue appears, and 100% clear as the blue comes off the screen. I would prob warp this whole thing in a closure, and cache the selectors so you don't have to call $() every time, but other than that - this should work.

- Your fiddle was a little different than your example above - but let me know if this is what you are looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/gmydzzmf/1/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  var st          = $(this).scrollTop(),
      win_height = $(window).height(),
      offset      = $('.two').offset().top - $('.two').height() - ( win_height / 2),
      _docHeight  = $('.one').height() + $('.two').height();

       if (st<offset ){
            // fading in
            opacity = st/offset; 
       } else { 
            // fading out 
            opacity = ((_docHeight - st)/(win_height*2));
       }
        $('.overlay').height(_docHeight); //move this to resize event
            $('.overlay').css('opacity', opacity);

});
```

Comment: It's close!  I wanted the opacity to begin fading out again *after* the blue section left the viewport.  I will play around with yours and see if I can manage that result.  Thanks!